# How do I make a table adjust its size base on the total width of the columns?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Please look at this table. This is the 
[Default Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iSBe.png) where 8 columns are showing.

But take a look at this other table. This is the table with
[More Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtKAN.png). But you can see that everything is so compact, what I expected is the horizontal scrollbar to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the behaviour through the [`JTable#setAutoResizeMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode(int)) method.

Passing it `JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF` will stop the table from automatically sizing the columns to "fit" the view area and will rely instead on the properties provided by the underlying `TableColumnModel`

This will place a much greater responsibility for managing the column widths on you, but will provide you with the overall desired result that when the total columns width is greater then the viewable area, you will get the horizontal scroll bar

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Use JTable with JScrollPane and rewrite the resolution window if possible.

Reference:
https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-create-a-scrollable-jtable-component/

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-jtable